# How to get Q_PROPERTYs to show in Design Viiew

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qproperty

I have a class derived from QPushButton with Q_PROPERTYs but they do not appear in the Property Editor of Design Mode.

There is a QPushButton promoted to my custom class in the design view and I would expect the properties to automatically display in the Property Editor, at least the one with type "int". There is a good chance I am misunderstanding something simple.

Here is what looks like the relevant lines in the code:

```
class virtualButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(int number MEMBER m_number DESIGNABLE true USER true STORED true CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(buttons::keySet set MEMBER m_set DESIGNABLE true USER true STORED true CONSTANT)
...
```

The code compiles fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make a Qt plugin from your widget?

If it is only code and you use it via "propagate to" in Qt Designer, that won't make the trick, only providing a plugin works. Read more [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html) and in similar articles in official documentation.

In short -- you can provide Designer with libraries, made using Qt plugin framework, that would contain your widgets. Of course, if you consider it worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a lot of hassle.